# Difference between a node and vnode

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm confused about the concepts of nodes and vnodes.

Here's what I had read: The hierarchy of elements in Cassandra is:
Cluster - Data Centre - Rack-Server-Node 
The node was described as a data storage layer within a server and the server was the actual physical machine containing the Cassandra software.

From what I could understand,  it seems to me that vnodes are different/more efficient than nodes in certain cases.

However I'm having trouble placing them in this hierarchy.

Is vnode just a different kind of node in the above hierarchy. 
or
is it that after the concept of vnode was introduced,  the element called server in the above hierarchy is now called a node and the one called node in the above hierarchy is now called a vnode!

Answer (score 4):

You can see vnodes as a next step in the hierarchy you've described, after physical nodes.

Vnodes help redistribute data based on tokens when you are resizing your cluster and making data distribution much more flexible.

There's a good explanation from datastax site: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2

EDIT: In old versions of Cassandra, tokens were splitted in the way that each server had one token(range) and it was replicated between physical machines based on replication factor. vnodes architecture (also used in riak for example) makes virtualization of the "node" layer, splitting the ring into high number of token ranges (vnodes) and each physical node (cassandra service) has number of vnodes running on it. Please review the link provided, there's very good explanation with examples.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by physical nodes? I understood a node to be a data storage layer in a server(actual physical machine).

Comment: the cassandra instance

Comment: Are you saying that earlier, each server could have only a single node on it.  If that's true then there was no need to separately enlist them(in the hierarchy I had mentioned). Also I'm having trouble understanding the link. What are those sections of the rings(A, B, C) Are those tokens?  If yes,  then how can a node have more than one token? If no,  then are they a section of the allowed hash value range. Does that mean that the only difference between a node and a vnode is that vnode can have multiple chunks of the 'hash value range' whereas the node can have only one chunk of that range.

Comment: Please see my answer, I think it's pretty clear now.

Comment: Yes, saying token they mean token/values range (hash algorithm is applied on the partition key to decide on which node - in this case also a token). Virtualizing this level (vnodes) you can change number of such ranges for each physical node dynamically, and even giving different number of such nodes for different machines based on their performance (not recommended!!!!)

Answer (score 2):

Before Cassandra 1.2 each node was assigned a token. So adding/replacing a node implied some manual calculations of the initial_token property in cassandra.yaml and also significant data moves across the cluster.

> Cassandra’s 1.2 release introduced the concept of virtual nodes, also
>   called vnodes for short. Instead of assigning a single token to a
>   node, the token range is broken up into multiple smaller ranges. Each
>   physical node is then assigned multiple tokens. By default, each node
>   will be assigned 256 of these tokens, meaning that it contains 256
>   virtual nodes. Virtual nodes have been enabled by default since 2.0.

From Cassandra, The definitive guide, Jeff Carpenter & Eben Hewitt.

Vnodes are good because you can adjust the number of vnodes on each Cassandra instance (node), depending on the machine capabilities by adjusting num_tokens property in the cassandra.yaml file.

Token assignments for vnodes are calculated by the org.apache.cassandra.dht.tokenallocator.ReplicationAwareTokenAllocator class.